# Plies in Connect 4 minimax

Tags: minimax

How many plies deep can I realistically search using minimax in connect 4?
Is it possible to search through the entire game starting at turn 1?
If not, on what turn is it feasible to search the board fully?

Comment: This question is fully answered by the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

Based on personal experience I can tell you that from the starting position, if you really fine tune  your algorithm, with a coarse evaluation, and a good transposition table, you can get around 11 ply deep. If you want to include techniques that are not theoretically sound (but are good in practice), such as Late Move Reductions and Futility Pruning, 15 ply might be feasible.

When a column of the board fills up, the branching factor decreases from 7 to 6. This greatly increases how deep you can go. Depending on how full the board is, it would take between two to three columns full before you could search to the end of the game.